# Filter for payment gateways (WooCommerce) - in_array() expects parameter 2 to be array

Tags: php, woocommerce

I've got an

> PHP Warning:  in_array() expects parameter 2 to be array, null given

```
function my_custom_available_payment_gateways( $gateways ) 
{
    $chosen_shipping_rates = ( isset( WC()->session ) ) ? WC()->session->get( 'chosen_shipping_methods' ) : array();

    if ( in_array( 'flexible_shipping_single:7', $chosen_shipping_rates ) ) :
        unset( $gateways['bacs'] );
        unset( $gateways['ppcp-gateway'] );
        unset( $gateways['przelewy24'] );

    elseif ( in_array( 'flexible_shipping_single:8', $chosen_shipping_rates ) ) :
        unset( $gateways['bacs'] );
        unset( $gateways['ppcp-gateway'] );
        unset( $gateways['przelewy24'] );

    endif;
    return $gateways;
}

add_filter( 'woocommerce_available_payment_gateways', 'my_custom_available_payment_gateways' );
```

How to change this?

Comment: One has to assume `WC()->session->get( 'chosen_shipping_methods' )` is not returning an array, so how did you place data into that session variable

Answer (score 0):

Although `chosen_shipping_methods` is a native WC session variable, it is probably not being set yet (at the time of that error being shown).

Set your `$chosen_shipping_rates` variable like this:

```
$chosen_shipping_rates = WC()->session->chosen_shipping_methods ?? null;
```

And then wrap your `if...endif` code to this condition:

```
if( $chosen_shipping_rates ) {
    ...
}
```